# NtAllocateVirtualMemory terminates with error 0xC0000005

Tags: c++, winapi

When trying to allocate memory via NtAllocateVirtualMemory ( it works via VirtualAlloc , but I'm wondering how it will work via NTAPI ) and I don't understand what the reason is, I gave PAGE_EXECUTE_READ permissions, but I also failed to allocate

```
#include <Windows.h>

#define NT_SUCCESS(Status) ((NTSTATUS)(Status) >= 0)

unsigned char buffer[] = {
    0x90,       // NOP
    0x90,       // NOP
    0xcc,       // INT3
    0xc3        // RET
};
unsigned int buffer_len = 4;

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* pNtAllocateVirtualMemory)(
    HANDLE             ProcessHandle,
    PVOID*             BaseAddress,
    ULONG              ZeroBits,
    PULONG             RegionSize,
    ULONG              AllocationType,
    ULONG              Protect
); 
typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* pNtWriteVirtualMemory)(
    HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    PVOID BaseAddress,
    PVOID Buffer,
    SIZE_T BufferSize,
    PSIZE_T NumberOfBytesWritten
);

int main()
{

    PVOID exec_mem;
    BOOL rv;
    HANDLE rt;

    pNtAllocateVirtualMemory ntAllocateVirtualMemory = 
        (pNtAllocateVirtualMemory)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "NtAllocateVirtualMemory");

    NTSTATUS status = ntAllocateVirtualMemory(
        GetCurrentProcess(),
        &exec_mem,
        0,
        (PULONG)&buffer_len,
        MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,
        PAGE_READWRITE
    );
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        return -1;
    }

    pNtWriteVirtualMemory ntWriteVirtualMemory = 
        (pNtWriteVirtualMemory)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "NtWriteVirtualMemory");
    
    SIZE_T bytesWritten; 
    status = ntWriteVirtualMemory(
        GetCurrentProcess(),
        exec_mem,
        buffer,
        buffer_len,
        &bytesWritten
    );

    rt = CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)exec_mem, 0, 0, 0);
    WaitForSingleObject(rt, -1);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to change permissions, length, tried to pass the length as a pointer, it still failed.

Comment: `ZeroBits` parameter [is supposed to be](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntallocatevirtualmemory) `ULONG_PTR`, which I think is 64 bit on Win64 while `ULONG` is 32 bit.

Comment: `exec_mem` is uninitialized, containing random garbage, when passed to `NtAllocateVirtualMemory`

Comment: Yes, that's right, I just didn't see it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Igor Tandetnik's suggestion:

`ZeroBits` parameter is supposed to be `ULONG_PTR`

`exec_mem` is uninitialized, containing random garbage, when passed to `NtAllocateVirtualMemory`.